# connection refused error on goormide while previewing url of a js file

Tags: node.js, express

my code goes like this:

```
var express=require('express');
var app = express();
app.get("\", function(req,res){
    res.send("abc");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT,process.env.IP,function(){
      console.log("Server started");
});
```

I am using goormide and I'm not able to figure out how to preview this I have run the following command on the terminal:

```
node app.js
```

where app.js is my file name
However when I run it on url then I'm getting connection refused error.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me to figure out how to run the file on url.

Comment: How are you specifying the `environment vairables`, namely `PORT` and `IP`? Have you created a `.env` file where you've specified the values for  `PORT` and `IP`?

Comment: Why to create .env file ? I can directly register a url and port number by clicking on running url and port option right.

Answer (score -1):

Try starting your node application using the following command:

`PORT=3000 node app.js`

And update the `app.listen` part in the following way:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT, function(){
      console.log("Server started on", process.env.PORT);
});
```

This will allow you to access your node-application on `http://localhost:3000`.

Additionally, I guess you've used the wrong `slash` in your `app.get` statement.

You would want to change it to:

```
app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.send("abc");
});
```

Comment: You might also want to look into `https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv` package for using more than one environment variables in your node.js application.